# Copying different content from one column to another with one separator

Tags: mysql

There is a table in which there is a column 'abc', 'abc2', 'abc3', 'abc4':

In the column 'abc':

```
@ 123 @@ 1 2 3 @@ some text here @@
```

@ is a delimiter, the text between @ and @ can be any

Is it possible to transfer '123' from the column 'abc' to the column 'abc2', '1 2 3' in the column 'abc3', 'some text here' in the column 'abc4' using MySQL query?
The text between @ and @ can be any!

I tried to act this way

```
UPDATE db SET abc2 = SUBSTRING_INDEX (SUBSTRING_INDEX (abc, '@', - 1), '@', 1)
```

But how do I switch to the next delimiter @ for abc3?

Comment: a column name with a increment in it are suspect and a good candidate for normalisation.. Also you are using a delimiter (`@`) separated values those also are suspect and a good candidate for normalisation

Comment: "But how do I switch to the next delimiter @ for abc3?"  you have the `-1` in the wrong place.. `UPDATE db SET abc2 = SUBSTRING_INDEX (SUBSTRING_INDEX (abc, '@', 1), '@', -1)` should select the first element `(123)` and `UPDATE db SET abc2 = SUBSTRING_INDEX (SUBSTRING_INDEX (abc, '@', 2), '@', -1)` should select `(1 2 3)`

Comment: Thank you,  Raymond Nijland.